# Looking for a way to exclude variable of select statement from second half of select statement

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am looking for a way to select from the database like users from the top three, then the top five including the top three, excluding a previous selected top three.  Here is the code:

> $strSQL = "SELECT id FROM ".USERS_TABLE." ut, ".USER_MATCH_TABLE." umt
>           WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $where). " AND ut.id=umt.id_user AND (ut.a='$a1' OR ut.b='$b1' OR ut.c='$c1' OR ut.d='$d1' OR ut.e='$e1' OR ut.f='$f1' OR ut.g='$g1' OR ut.h='$h1' OR ut.i='$i1' OR ut.j='$j1' OR ut.k='$k1' OR ut.l='$l1' OR ut.m='$m1' OR ut.n='$n1' OR ut.o='$o1' OR ut.p='$p1' OR ut.q='$q1' OR ut.r='$r1' OR ut.s='$s1' OR ut.t='$t1' OR ut.u='$u1' OR ut.v='$v1' OR ut.w='$w1' OR ut.x='$x1' OR ut.y='$y1' OR ut.z='$z1' OR ut.aa='$aa1' OR ut.ab='$ab1' OR ut.ac='$ac1' OR ut.ad='$ad1' OR ut.ae='$ae1' OR ut.af='$af1' OR ut.ag='$ag1' OR ut.ah='$ah1') AND (ut.a='$a2' OR ut.b='$b2' OR ut.c='$c2' OR ut.d='$d2' OR ut.e='$e2' OR ut.f='$f2' OR ut.g='$g2' OR ut.h='$h2' OR ut.i='$i2' OR ut.j='$j2' OR ut.k='$k2' OR ut.l='$l2' OR ut.m='$m2' OR ut.n='$n2' OR ut.o='$o2' OR ut.p='$p2' OR ut.q='$q2' OR ut.r='$r2' OR ut.s='$s2' OR ut.t='$t2' OR ut.u='$u2' OR ut.v='$v2' OR ut.w='$w2' OR ut.x='$x2' OR ut.y='$y2' OR ut.z='$z2' OR ut.aa='$aa2' OR ut.ab='$ab2' OR ut.ac='$ac2' OR ut.ad='$ad2' OR ut.ae='$ae2' OR ut.af='$af2' OR ut.ag='$ag2' OR ut.ah='$ah2' or ut.a='$a1' OR ut.b='$b1' OR ut.c='$c1' OR ut.d='$d1' OR ut.e='$e1' OR ut.f='$f1' OR ut.g='$g1' OR ut.h='$h1' OR ut.i='$i1' OR ut.j='$j1' OR ut.k='$k1' OR ut.l='$l1' OR ut.m='$m1' OR ut.n='$n1' OR ut.o='$o1' OR ut.p='$p1' OR ut.q='$q1' OR ut.r='$r1' OR ut.s='$s1' OR ut.t='$t1' OR ut.u='$u1' OR ut.v='$v1' OR ut.w='$w1' OR ut.x='$x1' OR ut.y='$y1' OR ut.z='$z1' OR ut.aa='$aa1' OR ut.ab='$ab1' OR ut.ac='$ac1' OR ut.ad='$ad1' OR ut.ae='$ae1' OR ut.af='$af1' OR ut.ag='$ag1' OR ut.ah='$ah1')";
>       $rs = $dbconn->Execute($strSQL);

```
while ($array = $rs->FetchRow()) {
    $ids[] = $array[0];
}
```

the first set of the query is AND (ut.a='$a1'or etc.)  the second part is after the and and includes the first part for top three, four and five.  I want to exlcude anything that is included in the top three from the top five.  Any ideas?  i thought of an array but the complexity is beyond me.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't, for the life of me, understand what your query is doing, but the way you would solve the generic question you are asking is two have 2 queries, and union the results. Possible something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM ".USERS_TABLE." ut,
    ".USER_MATCH_TABLE." umt
WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $where). "
    AND ut.id = umt.id_user
    AND (
        ut.a = '$a1'
        OR ut.b = '$b1'
        OR ut.c = '$c1'
        OR ut.d = '$d1'
        OR ut.e = '$e1'
        OR ut.f = '$f1'
        OR ut.g = '$g1'
        OR ut.h = '$h1'
        OR ut.i = '$i1'
        OR ut.j = '$j1'
        OR ut.k = '$k1'
        OR ut.l = '$l1'
        OR ut.m = '$m1'
        OR ut.n = '$n1'
        OR ut.o = '$o1'
        OR ut.p = '$p1'
        OR ut.q = '$q1'
        OR ut.r = '$r1'
        OR ut.s = '$s1'
        OR ut.t = '$t1'
        OR ut.u = '$u1'
        OR ut.v = '$v1'
        OR ut.w = '$w1'
        OR ut.x = '$x1'
        OR ut.y = '$y1'
        OR ut.z = '$z1'
        OR ut.aa = '$aa1'
        OR ut.ab = '$ab1'
        OR ut.ac = '$ac1'
        OR ut.ad = '$ad1'
        OR ut.ae = '$ae1'
        OR ut.af = '$af1'
        OR ut.ag = '$ag1'
        OR ut.ah = '$ah1'
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT id
FROM ".USERS_TABLE." ut,
    ".USER_MATCH_TABLE." umt
WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $where). "
    AND ut.id = umt.id_user
    AND(
        ut.a = '$a2'
        OR ut.b = '$b2'
        OR ut.c = '$c2'
        OR ut.d = '$d2'
        OR ut.e = '$e2'
        OR ut.f = '$f2'
        OR ut.g = '$g2'
        OR ut.h = '$h2'
        OR ut.i = '$i2'
        OR ut.j = '$j2'
        OR ut.k = '$k2'
        OR ut.l = '$l2'
        OR ut.m = '$m2'
        OR ut.n = '$n2'
        OR ut.o = '$o2'
        OR ut.p = '$p2'
        OR ut.q = '$q2'
        OR ut.r = '$r2'
        OR ut.s = '$s2'
        OR ut.t = '$t2'
        OR ut.u = '$u2'
        OR ut.v = '$v2'
        OR ut.w = '$w2'
        OR ut.x = '$x2'
        OR ut.y = '$y2'
        OR ut.z = '$z2'
        OR ut.aa = '$aa2'
        OR ut.ab = '$ab2'
        OR ut.ac = '$ac2'
        OR ut.ad = '$ad2'
        OR ut.ae = '$ae2'
        OR ut.af = '$af2'
        OR ut.ag = '$ag2'
        OR ut.ah = '$ah2'
        OR ut.a = '$a1'
        OR ut.b = '$b1'
        OR ut.c = '$c1'
        OR ut.d = '$d1'
        OR ut.e = '$e1'
        OR ut.f = '$f1'
        OR ut.g = '$g1'
        OR ut.h = '$h1'
        OR ut.i = '$i1'
        OR ut.j = '$j1'
        OR ut.k = '$k1'
        OR ut.l = '$l1'
        OR ut.m = '$m1'
        OR ut.n = '$n1'
        OR ut.o = '$o1'
        OR ut.p = '$p1'
        OR ut.q = '$q1'
        OR ut.r = '$r1'
        OR ut.s = '$s1'
        OR ut.t = '$t1'
        OR ut.u = '$u1'
        OR ut.v = '$v1'
        OR ut.w = '$w1'
        OR ut.x = '$x1'
        OR ut.y = '$y1'
        OR ut.z = '$z1'
        OR ut.aa = '$aa1'
        OR ut.ab = '$ab1'
        OR ut.ac = '$ac1'
        OR ut.ad = '$ad1'
        OR ut.ae = '$ae1'
        OR ut.af = '$af1'
        OR ut.ag = '$ag1'
        OR ut.ah = '$ah1'
        )
```